# Multiple email input fields autofilling to same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a form with a variable number of email input fields. The user can click a button to add an additional email input if the wish. My form then maps out the inputs:

```
function renderEmailFields() {
  return [...Array(numberOfEmails).keys()].map((i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className={styles.inputContainer}>
         <InputValidatable
            autoFocus={true}
            className={styles.input}
            id={`supportSquadEmail-${i}`}
            isValid={Validation.isEmailAddress(inviteEmails[i])}
            name={`supportSquadEmail-${i}`}
            value={inviteEmails[i]}
            onChange={(e) => handleEmailChange(i, e)}
            placeholder="Enter email here..."
          />

 </div>
 );
});
}
```

```
const [inviteEmails, setInviteEmails] = useState(["", "", ""]);
const [numberOfEmails, setNumberOfEmails] = useState(3);

function handleEmailChange(index, e) {
   const placeHolderArray = inviteEmails;
   placeHolderArray[index] = e.target.value;
   setInviteEmails([...placeHolderArray]);
}
```

When I click on any of the email inputs, my Chrome browser gives my autocomplete options.  Selecting one of the autocomplete options is causing ALL of the email inputs to populate with that value.

Comment: Hey there, can you include some more code? Specifically, I'm interested in your handleEmailChange function.

Comment: @AmitMaraj no problem. I just added that code now.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious to see what the placeholderArray looks like before and after the assignment in that function. Similarly, you can try console.logging the value to see if that autcomplete value gets logged out more than once when selected.

Comment: If I place a console log in the `handleEmailChange` function I can see that after selecting the autofill option the function runs three times.  `inviteEmails` logs [ "email@gmail.com", "", "",], then ["email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", ""], and finally  ["email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "email@gmail.com"]

Comment: I think a good starting point here would be making a deep copy of your inviteEmails state array, then performing your manipulation on the copy. Right now, through reference, the new variable you're creating is pointing to the state array instead of a new one. You can do this with the following piece of code: let placeholderArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inputEmails)); Hope this helps!